# VBA loop through columns with nested for loops

Tags: excel, vba

I've never written code before but for a project I'm analyzing fantasy basketball stats to determine which teams would win in matchups. There are nine stat categories, 12 teams total, and in a matchup between teams 1 and 2, whichever team is better in a category gets a 1, and the other gets a 0. Ties give each .5. The totals are summed, and the winner is the team with more points.

I've written a macro that compares team 1 to all the others for each category and gives them a 1 or 0 for each accordingly. I'm having trouble writing a loop that then starts with team 2 and compares it to all the others. I've tried putting a for loop around the other two, but I can't seem to offset it properly or get it to work. Any help would be appreciated. My code is below. Thanks!

---

```
Sub WhoWins()

    Dim teamAcounter As Integer
    Dim teamBcounter As Integer
    Dim teamAanswercounter As Integer
    Dim teamBanswercounter As Integer
    'these counters keep track of where we are in the stats and answers


    Dim Number1 As Single
    Dim Number2 As Single
    'these are the numbers currently being used to determine a win


    Dim answer1 As Single
    Dim answer2 As Single
    Dim split As Single
    answer1 = 1
    split = 0.5
    answer2 = 0
    'these are used to store a winning/losing/draw value in answers

    teamAanswercounter = teamBcounter + 16
    teamBanswercounter = teamAanswercounter + 1


    Dim columncounter As Integer

    teamAcounter = 3

    For columncounter = 2 to 10


        For teamBcounter = 4 To 14



            Number1 = Cells(teamAcounter, columncounter).Value
            Number2 = Cells(teamBcounter, columncounter).Value

            If Number1 > Number2 Then
                Cells(teamAanswercounter, columncounter).Value = 1 'answer1
                Cells(teamBanswercounter, columncounter).Value = 0 'answer2

            ElseIf Number2 > Number1 Then
                Cells(teamAanswercounter, columncounter).Value = 0 'answer2
                Cells(teamBanswercounter, columncounter).Value = 1 'answer1

             ElseIf Number1 = Number2 Then
                Cells(teamAanswercounter, columncounter).Value = split
                Cells(teamBanswercounter, columncounter).Value = split

            End If

            teamAanswercounter = teamAanswercounter + 3
            teamBanswercounter = teamAanswercounter + 1

        Next teamBcounter
        'teamBcounter = 4
        'teamAcounter = 3
        teamAanswercounter = teamBcounter + 1
        teamBanswercounter = teamAanswercounter + 1


    Next columncounter


End Sub
```

---

[image: excel shapshot]

Comment: Interesting project! Can you post a snippet of the worksheet that houses all the team category stats? That would be really helpful in understanding your script

Comment: If you believe the answers are helpful, you are encouraged to upvote any of them. If an answer solved your problem, kindly mark it as accepted. This is the way to say thanks in SO. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on the code you would need.  I have commented it to help with understanding.

```
Sub WhoWins()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngTeams As Range
    Dim rngStats As Range
    Dim arrTeams As Variant
    Dim arrStats As Variant
    Dim arrResults() As Variant
    Dim TeamAIndex As Long  'Think of this as the row for Team A
    Dim TeamBIndex As Long  'Think of this as the row for Team B
    Dim StatIndex As Long   'Think of this as the column
    Dim ResultIndex As Long
    Dim NumTeams As Long
    Dim NumStats As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  'Change sheetname if necessary

    'Get the list of teams
    Set rngTeams = ws.Range("A3", ws.Range("A3").End(xlDown))

    'Get the range of statistics
    Set rngStats = rngTeams.Offset(, 1).Resize(, WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Rows(rngTeams.Row)) - 1)

    'Convert the ranges into arrays
    arrTeams = Application.Transpose(rngTeams.Value)
    arrStats = rngStats.Value
    NumTeams = UBound(arrTeams) - LBound(arrTeams) + 1
    NumStats = UBound(arrStats, 2) - LBound(arrStats, 2) + 1

    'Ready the results array
    ReDim arrResults(1 To WorksheetFunction.Combin(NumTeams, 2), 1 To 5)
        'arrResults columns
        '1 = TeamAName
        '2 = TeamAScore
        '3 = TeamBName
        '4 = TeamBScore
        '5 = Winner

    For TeamAIndex = LBound(arrTeams) To NumTeams - 1
        For TeamBIndex = TeamAIndex + 1 To NumTeams
            ResultIndex = ResultIndex + 1
            arrResults(ResultIndex, 1) = arrTeams(TeamAIndex)
            arrResults(ResultIndex, 2) = 0
            arrResults(ResultIndex, 3) = arrTeams(TeamBIndex)
            arrResults(ResultIndex, 4) = 0
            For StatIndex = LBound(arrStats, 2) To UBound(arrStats, 2)
                If arrStats(TeamAIndex, StatIndex) > arrStats(TeamBIndex, StatIndex) Then
                    'Team A wins the stat
                    arrResults(ResultIndex, 2) = arrResults(ResultIndex, 2) + 1
                ElseIf arrStats(TeamBIndex, StatIndex) > arrStats(TeamAIndex, StatIndex) Then
                    'Team B wins the stat
                    arrResults(ResultIndex, 4) = arrResults(ResultIndex, 4) + 1
                Else
                    'Tie
                    arrResults(ResultIndex, 2) = arrResults(ResultIndex, 2) + 0.5
                    arrResults(ResultIndex, 4) = arrResults(ResultIndex, 4) + 0.5
                End If
            Next StatIndex
            If arrResults(ResultIndex, 2) > arrResults(ResultIndex, 4) Then
                'Team A Wins the game
                arrResults(ResultIndex, 5) = arrTeams(TeamAIndex)
            ElseIf arrResults(ResultIndex, 4) > arrResults(ResultIndex, 2) Then
                'Team B Wins the game
                arrResults(ResultIndex, 5) = arrTeams(TeamBIndex)
            Else
                'Tie
                arrResults(ResultIndex, 5) = "Tie"
            End If
        Next TeamBIndex
    Next TeamAIndex

    'Output the results
    With ws.Cells(rngTeams.Row + rngTeams.Rows.Count + 1, "A").Resize(, UBound(arrResults, 2))
        .Value = Array("Team A", "Team A Score", "Team B", "Team B Score", "Winner")    'Column headers for the results
        .Offset(1).Resize(ResultIndex).Value = arrResults  'Results data
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your help! I'll be honest it was a bit complex for me, but I think I've worked through it. Granted, I couldn't write something like it, but I think I understand how it does what it does. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Refactored Code to make it more modular and hopefully easier to understand. Not tested but should work.

```
Sub WhoWins()

    Dim numberOfTeams As Long

    numberOfTeams = 12

    Dim dataStartOffset As Long

    dataStartOffset = 2

    Dim currentCompareRow As Long

    currentCompareRow = dataStartOffset + numberOfTeams + 2


    Dim teamAcounter As Integer

    For teamAcounter = 1 To numberOfTeams

        Dim teamBcounter As Integer

        'Use if you want dublicate compares: For teamBcounter = 1 To numberOfTeams
        For teamBcounter = teamAcounter + 1 To numberOfTeams
            'Ignore comparing team with itself
            If teamBcounter <> teamAcounter Then
                'Calls the CompareTeams subroutine below and sets teamADataRow in it to the value of dataStartOffset + teamAcounter, sets teamBDataRow in it to dataStartOffset + teamAcounter, ...
                CompareTeams dataStartOffset + teamAcounter, dataStartOffset + teamBcounter, currentCompareRow, currentCompareRow + 1
                'After everything in the CompareTeams subroutine is executed this is executed
                currentCompareRow = currentCompareRow + 3
            End If
        Next teamBcounter
    Next teamAcounter

End Sub


Sub CompareTeams(ByVal teamADataRow As Long, ByVal teamBDataRow As Long, ByVal teamAResultRow As Long, ByVal teamBResultRow As Long)

    Dim Number1 As Single
    Dim Number2 As Single

    Dim columncounter As Long

    For columncounter = 2 To 10

        Number1 = Cells(teamADataRow, columncounter).Value
        Number2 = Cells(teamBDataRow, columncounter).Value

        Cells(teamAResultRow, columncounter).Value = CompareValue(Number1, Number2)
        Cells(teamBResultRow, columncounter).Value = CompareValue(Number2, Number1)

    Next columncounter
End Sub

'the Values in () represent the values that have to given to the function, so if you call CompareValue(1,2) then toCompare becomes 1 and compareWith becomes 2
Function CompareValue(ByVal toCompare, ByVal compareWith) As Long

    If toCompare > compareWith Then
        CompareValue = 1
    ElseIf toCompare < compareWith Then
        CompareValue = 0
    ElseIf toCompare = compareWith Then
        CompareValue = 0.5
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I have a few questions about the code, if you've got time to answer that'd be great, but otherwise no worries and thanks for your help. 

In the For teamBcounter loop what does the "<>" do? Also where did you pull the next line from? It contains "CompareTeams" which I don't see before that. 

Also in the final function in the () you add "ByVal toCompare" etc. Does putting those in the () declare them? I don't see them anywhere else in the code/don't fully understand how that works. Thanks for all your help

Comment: <> only means not equal. so 1<>1 is false, 1<>2 is true

Answer (score 0):

This one was fun so I took a crack at it too. I split it into two functions: `LoadTeamStats` and `WhoWins`, with some basic safety checks for bad input etc. Heavily commented to make following along easy:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DoIt()
    Dim Result As String
    Result = WhoWins("Team 1", "Team 2")
    MsgBox Result & " Wins!"
End Sub
```

[image: run do it]

```
'compare two teams
Function WhoWins(TeamA As String, TeamB As String) As String
    Dim TeamARange As Range, TeamBRange As Range
    Dim TeamAVar As Variant, TeamBVar As Variant
    Dim Score As Single
    Dim Index As Long

    'safety check, make sure team names are defined
    If TeamA = vbNullString Then
        WhoWins = "Error, Team A Is Blank"
        Exit Function
    End If
    If TeamB = vbNullString Then
        WhoWins = "Error, Team B Is Blank"
        Exit Function
    End If

    'load team stats for comparison
    Set TeamARange = LoadTeamStats(TeamA)
    Set TeamBRange = LoadTeamStats(TeamB)

    'safety check, make sure teams were found
    If TeamARange Is Nothing Then
        WhoWins = "Error, Team A Not Found"
        Exit Function
    End If
    If TeamBRange Is Nothing Then
        WhoWins = "Error, Team B Not Found"
        Exit Function
    End If

    'build variant arrays and do comparison
    TeamAVar = TeamARange.Value
    TeamBVar = TeamBRange.Value
    For Index = LBound(TeamAVar) To UBound(TeamAVar)
        If TeamAVar(Index, 1) > TeamBVar(Index, 1) Then
            Score = Score + 1
        ElseIf TeamAVar(Index, 1) < TeamBVar(Index, 1) Then
            Score = Score - 1
        End If
    Next Index

    'determine the winner
    If Score > 0 Then
        WhoWins = TeamA
    ElseIf Score < 0 Then
        WhoWins = TeamB
    Else
        WhoWins = "No one"
    End If
End Function

'load a team's stats
Function LoadTeamStats(TeamName As String) As Range
    Dim Found As Range
    Dim TargetRow As Long
    Dim Source As Worksheet

    'safety check, make sure TeamName is not blank
    If TeamName = vbNullString Then
        LoadTeamStats = Nothing
        Exit Function
    End If

    'set references and find team
    Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Found = Source.Cells.Find(TeamName, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    'safety check, make sure the team was found
    If Found Is Nothing Then
        LoadTeamStats = Nothing
        Exit Function
    End If

    'otherwise, team was found and need to load range
    TargetRow = Found.Row
    With Source
        Set LoadTeamStats = .Range(.Cells(TargetRow, 2), .Cells(TargetRow, 10))
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: thanks a lot! The code was clear and easy for me to understand with all the comments

Comment: what would you add to this code to make it compute all matchups and the winners?

Answer (score 0):

Throwing in my two cents, as I am a fan of fantasy basketball myself. Here's the code I use, adjusted for your personal set-up.

```
Function GetStats(TeamName As String) As Object

    'This returns a dictionary object.

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim TeamNameRange As Range, TeamNameCell As Range
    Dim TeamNameRow As Long
    Dim StatsRange As Range, StatsCell As Range
    Dim TeamDict As Object

    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With WS
        Set TeamNameRange = .Range("A2:A13")
        Set StatsRange = .Range("B1:J1")
    End With
    Set TeamDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each TeamNameCell In TeamNameRange
        If TeamNameCell.Value = TeamName Then
            TeamNameRow = TeamNameCell.Row
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    With TeamDict
        For Each StatsCell In StatsRange
            .Add StatsCell.Value, StatsCell.Offset(TeamNameRow - 1, 0).Value
        Next
    End With

    Set GetStats = TeamDict

End Function

Function MatchUp(HomeTeamName As String, AwayTeamName As String) As String

    Dim HomeTeamStats As Object, AwayTeamStats As Object
    Dim HomeTeamScore As Double, AwayTeamScore As Double
    Dim Res As String

    Set HomeTeamStats = GetStats(HomeTeamName)
    Set AwayTeamStats = GetStats(AwayTeamName)

    HomeTeamScore = 0
    AwayTeamScore = 0

    For Each Key In HomeTeamStats.Keys
        If HomeTeamStats(Key) > AwayTeamStats(Key) Then
            HomeTeamScore = HomeTeamScore + 1
        ElseIf HomeTeamStats(Key) < AwayTeamStats(Key) Then
            AwayTeamScore = AwayTeamScore + 1
        ElseIf HomeTeamStats(Key) = AwayTeamStats(Key) Then
            HomeTeamScore = HomeTeamScore + 0.5
            AwayTeamScore = AwayTeamScore + 0.5
        End If
    Next

    Res = HomeTeamScore & " - " & AwayTeamScore
    If HomeTeamScore > AwayTeamScore Then
        Res = "W " & Res & " L"
    ElseIf HomeTeamScore < AwayTeamScore Then
        Res = "L " & Res & " W"
    ElseIf HomeTeamScore = AwayTeamScore Then
        Res = "T " & Res & " T"
    End If

    MatchUp = Res

End Function

Function MatchUpTwo(HomeTeamName As String, AwayTeamName As String) As String

    Dim HomeTeamStats As Object, AwayTeamStats As Object
    Dim HomeTeamScore As Double, AwayTeamScore As Double
    Dim Res As String

    Set HomeTeamStats = GetStats(HomeTeamName)
    Set AwayTeamStats = GetStats(AwayTeamName)

    HomeTeamScore = 0
    AwayTeamScore = 0

    For Each Key In HomeTeamStats.Keys
        If HomeTeamStats(Key) > AwayTeamStats(Key) Then
            HomeTeamScore = HomeTeamScore + 1
        ElseIf HomeTeamStats(Key) < AwayTeamStats(Key) Then
            AwayTeamScore = AwayTeamScore + 1
        ElseIf HomeTeamStats(Key) = AwayTeamStats(Key) Then
            HomeTeamScore = HomeTeamScore + 0.5
            AwayTeamScore = AwayTeamScore + 0.5
        End If
    Next

    If HomeTeamScore > AwayTeamScore Then
        Res = "WIN"
    ElseIf HomeTeamScore < AwayTeamScore Then
        Res = "LOSE"
    ElseIf HomeTeamScore = AwayTeamScore Then
        Res = "TIE"
    End If

    MatchUpTwo = Res

End Function
```

Paste the above code to a regular module. You can use it as formula in the format of `=MatchUp("Team1", "Team2")` or `=MatchUpTwo("Team1", "Team2")`.

The difference between `MatchUp` and `MatchUpTwo` is that the latter outputs a word rather than a score. Basically, the home team is the first argument and the away team is the latter argument. If it outputs `WIN`, then the home team won. `LOSE`, and you get the point.

The above two variants both use the `GetStats` function, which creates a dictionary of stats. So you can add more stats to the left, more teams down, and it will scale properly.

For a nice application of how this is best used in table format, see the following screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, my reference table is in `A1`. My upper match-up table uses the `MatchUp` function, while the one below uses the `MatchUpTwo` function, with an additional conditional formatting. Check the formula bar how to set up the formula. Just input and drag.

Seems like `Team 1` sucks the most on my end. ;)

Enjoy and let us know if this helps.