# Error in Loop when using Month and Year function with integer

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue getting my code to work properly.  Im trying to compare the month and year in column K to the Month and Year in Cell P2.  Then if they are a match, copy and paste a value located Column J (if greater than 0) to Column P.  I have pasted my code below.  Im not getting any errors, but it is not pasting values either.  Any help is appreciated.  I also include the code I wrote to get the formulas correct (at bottom).  It worked correctly.

Eventually I would like to compare the date in Column K to the dates in Cell P2 - AA2 which each contain a different month of the year (January 2017, February 2017, etc..), but I think If I can get this first loop working, I can figure out the next piece.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim i As Integer
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    For i = 3 To 6
        If Month(Range("K" & i)) & Year(Range("K" & i)) = Month(Range("P2")) & Year(Range("P2")) Then
        ElseIf Range("J" & i).Value > "0" Then
            Range("J" & i).Copy
            Range("P" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next i
End Sub


'Original Code I wrote to get the formulas correct before adding the loop and variables

'Sheets("Sheet1").Select
'If Month(Range("K3")) & Year(Range("K3")) = Month(Range("P2")) & Year(Range("P2")) Then
'  If Range("J3").Value > "0" Then
'  Range("J3").Copy
'  Range("P3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'  Else
'  End If
'Else
'End If
'End Sub
```

Comment: I believe your if statements are wrong. try this for the first one and apply the same changes type of chamnges to the seondon one. `If Month(Range("K" & i)) = Month(Range("P2")) And Year(Range("K" & i)) =  Year(Range("P2")) Then`

Comment: Please format your code next time.

Comment: As @sourceCode said your statement is wrong. `If Month(Range("K" & i)) = Month(Range("P2")) And Year(Range("K" & i)) = Year(Range("P2")) And 
Range("J" & i).Value > 0 Then`

Comment: That ended up working.  Thanks!  Never would have thought to group it that way.

Comment: A quick follow up on the second part of my question.  I would like to be able to compare column K to the dates listed in cells P2 to AA2.  I had P2 fixed at first while I was figuring out the code.  So essentially I would like to make the column letter an additional variable within this loop.  So when the loop is on cell K3 it will compare it to all dates in columns P2 - AA2 and look for a match.  Any recommendations on how to do this?  I can start a new question if necessary

Comment: @MattR Have a look on nested for loops iterators like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802716/vba-nested-loop-to-find-each-value-of-a-column-in-a-different-spreadsheet or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189773/vba-loop-through-columns-with-nested-for-loops and the function .Column property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-column-property-excel If you have further questions, it is better to open another question